# Chrome stuck on 'resolving host'

Tags: networking, google-chrome

So for a little while now my Chrome has been randomly not loading new webpages. Already open pages work fine - like, facebook chat continues to function, for example - and other programs are fine. The problem persists after a full restart of Chrome, but not after a reboot. The problem fixes itself eventually - I know not how. Can anyone make sense of the following?...

```
user@chrubuntu:~$ google-chrome-stable
[8144:8144:0528/194948:ERROR:component_loader.cc(138)] Failed to parse extension manifest.
[8144:8144:0528/194948:ERROR:background_mode_manager_aura.cc(14)] Not implemented reached in virtual void BackgroundModeManager::EnableLaunchOnStartup(bool)
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
Gen6+ requires Kernel 3.6 or later.
/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-proce: ../../../../src/mesa/main/context.c:1549: _mesa_make_current: Assertion `newCtx->Version > 0' failed.
[8144:8144:0528/194948:ERROR:desktop_window_tree_host_x11.cc(1289)] Not implemented reached in void views::DesktopWindowTreeHostX11::MapWindow(ui::WindowShowState)
--2014-05-28 19:49:48--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... [8144:8144:0528/194950:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(440)] Failed to establish GPU channel.
failed: Connection timed out.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘clients2.google.com’
[8144:8266:0528/195000:ERROR:get_updates_processor.cc(214)] PostClientToServerMessage() failed during GetUpdates
[8144:8175:0528/195016:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(287)] Failed to connect to MCS endpoint with error -137
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add 2 lines end of the file `/etc/resolve.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

and then

```
sudo service network restart
```

and you can visit https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/.

Comment: This did the trick for me on Ubuntu 16.04. I had noticed that in Chrome, when loading a page, there would be an initial delay of a few seconds while it said "Resolving host..." in the lower left. After adding Google's DNS servers to my resolv.conf, page load is much faster.

Worth noting: at least on my system, there was a warning at the top of resolv.conf about not editing resolv.conf directly. I followed the instructions [here](https://itsfoss.com/resolvconf-permanent-ubuntu/) and edited /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head instead to make the change permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your browser cache with the following code in Google Chrome: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> then restart Google Chrome en chek if the problem has been resolved.

Comment: Tried this - after several attempts to make sure (the whole thing was very erratic), I'm not sure it was doing anything useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

Step 1:
Checking Default route
Use one of these commands:

```
route -n
```

or

```
ip r
```

Ask a new IP address and amend the connection with the next command:

```
dhclient -v wlan0
```

Now, all should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix:

```
 1) install resolvconf app  "sudo apt install resolvconf"
 2) sudo service networking restart
```

Or if resolvconf is already installed:

```
 1) sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
 2) sudo service networking restart
```

This fixes the DNS resolution issue on Ubuntu and Linux Mint. The resolvconf program changes /etc/resolv.conf file and acts as an intermediary between programs which use that file (here Chrome).